# Sso on website using winforms and identityserver4

Tags: winforms, identityserver4, openid-connect

For my company we need a solution for the following simple scenario:
We have a winforms app, on which we login locally.
In this winforms app there is a help button, upon pressing this a web browser should open and the user is authenticated in help site without having to enter credentials again.
The help site uses OpenId-connect to authorize.

We want to use Identityserver as a base.
I have looked into this example: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis
The steps here (for openid connect) are:
1 access authorized page on help site
2 site redirects to identityserver login page
3 user logs in and identiyserver redirects to redirectpage with a authorization code
4 help site picks up this auth code and exchanges this for a valid token.
5 user is authenticated

I understand the redirect principle, but having the user to sign in again is annoying.
So what I want to do (I think) is:
1 log into identityserver token endpoint and obtain token using clientid/client secret programmatically in the winforms app
2 Somehow obtain an authorization code to skip the login process from step 2 and
3 open a browser with the url and code from step 3.

Is this somehow possible?

UPDATE i have concluded openid connect is not the right the right way to go for my situation

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be to have the user sign into the winforms app using your IDP too. This is certainly doable but can you explain what the "login locally" step entains and what that ultimately grants access to? i.e. what resources does the winforms app gain access to via the local login process?

Comment: Well the winforms app is a software package we sell. So user details on customer side is of none importance, It's just a username and pw in a local db. My plan is to make one general user on the help site, and use that account for all customers as entrypoint.

Comment: I can get a token from the token endpoint within winforms app, but how do i use this token to authorize @ the authorize endpoint, without having to show the login screen. I basically have to let identityserver know the user is already athenticated, and get a web session.

Comment: To have "SSO" you need to be signing in the same way into each product/application. That's why I was trying to gleen how you currently do sign ins. If your winforms app was to use the same  IDP as your support portal then you'd get SSO for free. I'd avoid trying to invent new protocols for bridging this gap if at all possible

Comment: Ok, i checked the ids example clients, but no such thing. If i sign in in winforms, how do i automatically authenticate the browser session then? Still sends me to login page every time which makes sense of course. I need to let ids know that user is already signed in, aquire the authentication-code programmatically somehow, but no luck. Is there a sample of this situation somewhere you know of?

Comment: You'd change your winforms app to sign in (using the user's default browser) via your IDP - this is the current best practice when using OIDC with native apps. If this is something you don't want to do then I don't think OpenID Connect is the right solution here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mackie said in last comment, openid connect is not the right solution for this. I'm looking at other technologies like one time password link to achieve what we need. Thank you Mackie

Comment: You can mention this in the comments as it is a response to a comment.